# EnyoJS: Call enyo functions from raw JavaScript

Tags: javascript, enyo

In "old" enyo for HPalm devices I was able to call my enyo kind functions from/via JS like this:

```
<span class="button" onclick="app.doSomething();"></span>
```

Now in enyoJS it doesn't work. My app.js looks like this:

```
enyo.kind({
    name: "myapp.Application",
    kind: "enyo.Application",
    view: "myapp.MainView"
});

enyo.ready(function () {
    new myapp.Application({name: "app"});
});
```

I tried pretty much everything I could think of, but nothing seams to do the trick anymore.

```
var app = new myapp.MainView();
app.renderInto(document.body);
app.doSomething();
```

^ etc does not work either.

My MainView:

```
enyo.kind({
    name: "myapp.MainView",
    kind: "FittableRows",
    classes: "enyo-fit enyo-unselectable",
    fit: true,
    components:[
        //... stuff here ...
    ],

    doSomething: function(){
        console.log("Hello!");      
    }   
});
```

Is there a way how to achieve what I need? TYVM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track. In fact, your attempt to create MainView directly [works](http://codepen.io/ryanjduffy/pen/mdjfC).

The reason `app.doSomething()` doesn't work is:

- app doesn't exist in the global space and
- app doesn't have a doSomething method; MainView does

There are a couple ways to get a reference to your Application instance. The easiest is to assign it to a global on create:

```
var app;
enyo.ready(function() {
    app = new myapp.Application({name: "app"});
});

// later
app.doSomething();
```

Another option is to grab it from the `enyo.applications` hash which stores a reference to each created application by its name.

```
enyo.applications.app.doSomething();
```

Here's a [complete example](http://codepen.io/ryanjduffy/pen/GLCuq?editors=001)

```
enyo.kind({
    name: "myapp.Application",
    kind: "enyo.Application",
    view: "myapp.MainView",
    doSomething: function() {
      this.$.mainView.doSomething();
    }
});

enyo.kind({
    name: "myapp.MainView",
    kind: "FittableRows",
    classes: "enyo-fit enyo-unselectable",
    fit: true,
    components:[
        //... stuff here ...
    ],

    doSomething: function(){
        console.log("Hello!");      
    }   
});

enyo.ready(function () {
    var app = new myapp.Application({name: "app"});

    // works, but not recommended as it breaks encapsulation
    // app.$.mainView.doSomething();

    // preferred but requires a little extra code
    app.doSomething();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that global approach, but it didn't work - that's why I'm confused. Same for: "enyo.applications.app.doSomething();". Your 3rd example works fine - THANK YOU. :)